# GIMP - change color of object preserving feathering

Tags: colors, transparency, gimp

I have an .xcf image and I like to change the color of some objects within it. The objects are mostly one solid color with the edges feathered into transparency. I.e. all pixels in the object are white with most pixels fully opaque and some with transparency.

I've tried to change the objects' color using the color select tool + bucket fill but this destroys the feathering. Is there a way to get the gimp to change just the color but preserve the transparency?

The actual objects that I have are multiple bits of text all at different sizes and rotations that I have merged into one layer. So it is no use re-adding the feathering as this messes up the text quite noticeably.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to preserve the opacity/transparency of the layer while using the bucket fill tool, you can click the "Lock Transparency" button in the layers dialog (see image below).

[image: example image]

Then, you can either create a selection of the objects or simply fill the entire image with the bucket tool. The alpha of the layer will remain unmodified.

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail?  When I tried what I think you said, flood-fill maintained the transparency, but surprised me with a really different color.

Comment: @ScottBiggs - make sure the layer isn't in some weird mode (i.e. that's in normal, and not hard light or anything like that), and that the bucket tool itself is also in normal mode (and not any other mode)